# How to execute a code from another script and pass arguments

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I have a python code **try.py** which has to execute another one called **prova.py**.
I do it as folows and it works:

```
exec(open("prova.py").read())
```

Now, I have some variables I need to pass to **prova.py**, and I did it as follows according to what found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/

```
var = {key:val for key, val in enumerate(lista_gp_todict)}
exec(open("prova.py").read(), var)
```

**try.py** does not give error which means the way I write exec now is still correct in terms of syntax, but in the moment this exec runs it gives error in **prova.py**:

```
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

which mean that the code **prova.py** which has inside the variable *var* does not recognise it, like it was not declared. In fact *var* is not declared into **prova.py** because if I pass it I assume it already there.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: my OS is windows

Comment: you can import it to your main script tho

Comment: mmm I did not think of it, thanks. Can you elaborate a bit more please? how should I code that?

Comment: my prova.py is a script, not a function, usually I import classes or funtions, not script

Comment: may i see the script ... did you use any function ?

Comment: u can import the script and use the function .. doesnt have to be class

Comment: I imported the script in the main as you suggested: import prova var = {key:val for key, val in enumerate(lista_gp_todict)} exec(prova, var), it still says var is not defined. I cannot show the codes as they are quite big. To answer your question they are both scripts, they contain some functions but in general they are both scripts

Comment: Do you know about `subprocess.run()`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run In your example `subprocess.run(['python', 'prova.py', var])` and in `prova.py`, `var = sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: @Axe319 thanks a lot, unfortunately it is not working as it says: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict I guess is due to var which in my case is a dictionary. I made it a list but it gives me error again as expected. var is a list/dict of strings

Comment: @Dark2018 In that case, you could pass it as `json` with `subprocess.run(['python', 'prova.py', json.dumps(var)])` and load it again with `var = json.loads(sys.argv[1])` as long as your `dict` isn't too big.

Comment: that works, thanks mate. If you provide an answer I will accept yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would call another script with the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) module.

`subprocess.run()` accepts an iterable of strings as arguments to be run as a separate process. You can use the arguments exactly as you would call them from command line.

```
subprocess.run(['python', 'prova.py', my_argument])
```

Since you wish to pass a `dict` to your script, you can do so by first serializing to `json`, which is just a nice way of saying "convert it to a string".

Since `var` is your `dict` you can do so like.

```
subprocess.run(['python', 'prova.py', json.dumps(var)])
```

And then deserialize or "convert back to a `dict`" in `prova.py`.

```
var = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
```

Alternatively, you could `import` `prova.py` if all you intend to use from it are functions, classes, or variables.

For example, if `prova.py` contains:

```
# prova.py
def my_func(var):
   # do some stuff to var
```

You can then do this in your main script:

```
import prova
var = {key:val for key, val in enumerate(lista_gp_todict)}
prova.my_func(var)
```